# Reverse "formula" based on a string

Tags: c++

Is possible to make the reverse process of that?

```
string dir = textenc.Text;
uint EDI = 0x1505;
uint EDX = 0;
byte ECX = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < dir.Length; i++ )
{
    if ( dir[ i ] != '.' && dir[ i ] != '\\' )
    {
        EDX = EDI;
        EDX = EDX << 5;
        ECX = ( byte )dir[ i ];
        EDX = EDX + EDI;
        EDX = EDX + ECX;
        EDI = EDX;
    }
};
return EDI;
```

The `dir` is a string, for example, when `dir` is `"data\font\tahoma.ttf"` the output of that function would be: `2114405758`.

Is there a way to retrieve the original string giving only the output number?

Comment: Looks like a hash function, so no.

Comment: This cannot be possible in general as there are *way* more strings than there are integers. The function cannot be a bijection and therefore is not invertible in general.

Comment: No way to reverse that?

Comment: @CainanKenjiKita: No. Easiest way to see is with a simplified example. Map every vowel to 1 and the rest to 0. Which word was "0110"?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The hash function ignores the characters `.` and `\`. You can add as many as these as you want, and it will still calculate the same value.

Note: As mentioned by others, this is a hash function, which will create infinitely many collisions.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **NO**, it is not possible.

---

The long answer is that it will be nearly impossible to tell if the generated hash is unique to the input given.

The only way to know this is to generate hashes for all possible string combinations until you hit a duplicate; Or you don't hit a duplicate, but you will run out of memory before the later happens. There is also the case that you don't hit duplicates for a long time which can also mean that the hash function is quite good but still does not mean it is reversible.

Comment: It's generally **easy** to find two inputs which hash to the same value. Only specific **cryptographic** hashes are collision-resistant. For those, brute-forcing is necessary. There's no need whatsoever to brute-force simple hashes such as CRC32.